# modify the classname part of Keras ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I was wondering if it is possible to change the `flow_from_directory` function in order to give my desired `class names`.

For example, I have folders with names `101, 102` and with `flow_from_directory` I'll have `y`/`class names` as `101` and `102`, but I need to have `[1,0,1]` and `[0,1,0]` in `y` for **multi-label classification**.

Something like this in `flow_from_directory`.

```
if folder_name == 101:
    y=[1,0,1]
if folder_name == 102:
    y=[0,1,0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to assign a list to single class name in `flow_from_directory` you will get an error

For multi-label classification , create a pandas Dataframe with file name and labels as columns like this example and use `flow_from_dataframe` instead

[image]

Tthen create your train generator with train dir as directory for images

```
train_gen = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_dataframe(
    df,
    directory=train_dir,
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='labels',
    class_mode='categorical'
)
```

Comment: I am doing it for multi-label classification, does string like "[1,0]" will serve for it?

Comment: Sorry did not notice its for mutli-label , in this case you have to put filenames and label in a dataframe as use flow_from_dataframe

Comment: ok now that worked. @Yefet please edit your initial answer so that I choose it as the right answer !

(for those you are in this step and looking forward to continue) 
I continued with this medium article, and that worked well https://medium.com/@ckyeungac/a-simple-trick-about-multi-label-image-classification-with-imagedatagenerator-in-keras-4ab95364a481

Comment: Done and sorry for being late! glad i helped

Comment: yep, it helped me to get on the right way! thanks